# Cannot reset value of Checked items in checkbox event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first time to develop a react application.

I am working with getting the row id of the ticked checkbox in a react table.
I used hooks to transfer the states to another component that will display the values. When the checkbox is ticked then unticked, the unticked id is still displaying in the state. Am I missing something that will refresh the value of state?

Thank you very much.

```
export default function({ infinite }) {
const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());
rows.forEach(row => newMap.set(row, false));

const handleCheckedChange = transaction_seq => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq));
    setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
  };

const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Transaction(s)",
      className: "left",
      columns: [
        {
          id: "checkbox",
          accessor: "checkbox",
          Cell: ({ row }) => {
            return (
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                checked={checkedMap.get(row.original.transaction_seq)}
                onChange={() =>
                  handleCheckedChange(row.original.transaction_seq)
                }
              />
            );
          },

          sortable: false,
          width: 45
        }

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table
        {...{
          data,
          checkedMap,
```

Edit: I added index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//import makeData from "../makeData";
import { useTableState } from "react-table";
import Table from "../Table";
import axios from "axios";

// Simulate a server
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

  // Ideally, you would pass this info to the server, but we'll do it here for convenience
  const filtersArr = Object.entries(filters);

  // Get our base data
  const res = await axios.get(
    `url`
  );
  let rows = res.data;

  // Apply Filters
  if (filtersArr.length) {
    rows = rows.filter(row =>
      filtersArr.every(([key, value]) => row[key].includes(value))
    );
  }

  // Apply Sorting
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const [{ id, desc }] = sortBy;
    rows = [...rows].sort(
      (a, b) => (a[id] > b[id] ? 1 : a[id] === b[id] ? 0 : -1) * (desc ? -1 : 1)
    );
  }

  // Get page counts
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(rows.length / pageSize);
  const rowStart = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const rowEnd = rowStart + pageSize;

  // Get the current page
  rows = rows.slice(rowStart, rowEnd);

  return {
    rows,
    pageCount
  };
};

export default function({ infinite }) {
  const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const currentRequestRef = useRef();
  const [controlButton] = useState(0);

  let newMap = new Map();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // We can use a ref to disregard any outdated requests
    const id = Date.now();
    currentRequestRef.current = id;

    // Call our server for the data
    const { rows, pageCount } = await getServerData({
      filters,
      sortBy,
      pageSize,
      pageIndex
    });

    // If this is an outdated request, disregard the results
    if (currentRequestRef.current !== id) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the data and pageCount
    setData(rows);
    setState(old => ({
      ...old,
      pageCount
    }));

    rows.forEach(row => newMap.set(row, false));
    //setCheckedMap(newMap);

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleCheckedChange = transaction_seq => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    const chh = modifiedMap.set(
      transaction_seq,
      !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq)
    );
    setCheckedMap(chh);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Transaction(s)",
      className: "left",
      columns: [
        {
          id: "checkbox",
          accessor: "checkbox",
          Cell: ({ row }) => {
            return (
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                checked={checkedMap.get(row.original.transaction_seq)}
                onChange={() =>
                  handleCheckedChange(row.original.transaction_seq)
                }
              />
            );
          },

          sortable: false,
          width: 45
        },
        {
          Header: "Transaction Sequence",
          accessor: "transaction_seq",
          id: "transaction_seq",
          minWidth: 200,
          maxWidth: 300
        },
        {
          Header: "Record count",
          accessor: "record_count",
          width: 300
        },
        {
          Header: "User Id",
          accessor: "user_id",
          width: 300
        },
        {
          Header: "Updated At",
          accessor: "update_at",
          width: 400
        },
        {
          Header: "Duration",
          accessor: "duration",
          width: 400
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // Make a new controllable table state instance
  const state = useTableState({ pageCount: 0 });

  const [{ sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize }, setState] = state;

  // When sorting, filters, pageSize, or pageIndex change, fetch new data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table
        {...{
          data,
          checkedMap,
          controlButton,
          columns,
          infinite,
          state, // Pass the state to the table
          loading,
          manualSorting: true, // Manual sorting
          manualFilters: true, // Manual filters
          manualPagination: true, // Manual pagination
          disableMultiSort: true, // Disable multi-sort
          disableGrouping: true, // Disable grouping
          debug: true
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is immutable.js?

When you `set` a value in a `Map`, the new `Map` is *returned* to you:

So, this:

```
modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq));
setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
```

Should be:

```
const updatedMap = modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq));
setCheckedMap(updatedMap);
```

Comment: Hi Davin, the solution provided above does not resolve the problem, it still returns the unticked values.

Comment: what is the value that you are setting?

Comment: transaction_seq (row value in the table) are the ones stored in checkedMap hook

Comment: Hi Davin, I also added the index.js